# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shift')

Tags: vue.js, content-management-system, statamic

I'm getting the following error (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shift') whenever I make changes to the Mailchimp settings in the Statamic CMS and save the changes. The error appears when I refresh the page to see if the changes remain there. The reason I have to refresh is due to it not saving properly sometimes. 70% of the time it will save my changes as expected, but the other 30% after I click "save changes", it says it saves successfully but if I then refresh the page, it reverts back to what it had before. I seen other solutions before talking about Waypoint and counterup but I don't have any of that included within my project. I don't have any idea where this issue could possibly be coming from at the moment so apologies for not having any code to provide or any specification for where I think it may be. Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

```
vue.common.prod.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shift')
at a.list (cp.js:1)
at fn.get (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at fn.evaluate (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at a.list (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at a.<anonymous> (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at fn.get (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at new fn (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at a.e.$watch (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at yn (vue.common.prod.js:6)
at vue.common.prod.js:6
```

This is what I also looked at: https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/10

It works fine for me locally but not on staging. I think it may be an environmental issue.

Comment: Still struggling with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this one out by now but I just thought I'd update this thread in case anyone runs into this in the future.

This sounds like a bug in the Mailchimp Statamic addon, which is built by a third-party. I'd recommend opening a bug report on the addon's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/silentzco/statamic-mailchimp). Hopefully then, you'll get a response back from the developer.